# SQL insert data into column

Tags: sql

I have added a new column added `'region'` into MyTable

```
alter MyTable 
add (Region varchar2(20))
```

I have also a `'telephone number'` column in MyTable and now I need to put all that data from my telephone number column into MyTable.

What is the quickest way to do this?

If you have any idea, your free to post!

Comment: Where is the data for the telephone number currently stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to update your region field to the value in your telephone number column?  If so, simple update statement should do:

```
update mytable
set region = telephone
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE MyTable SET `region` = `telephone_number`
```